# How to use NSPersistentContainer with NSPersistentDocument

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

Nowadays all core data examples are iOS examples, so there isn't much guidance for macOS since the interesting changes to core data in macOS 10.12. But I would like to see how the NSPersistentContainer is supposed to work with a multi-document setup. Who has a good tutorial etc.? How is the stack now supposed to work? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: NSPersistentDocument is very straightforward. I don't have a good tutorial, but it is easy. What do you want to know?

Comment: I have a working stack. Or better I had until NSColor wasn't easily de- & encoded. While I was able to make it work again I realise that saving into a new file is an issue for not de- & encode NSColor (surprise). Then I came across this new NSPersistentContainer and try to see whether my framework is outdated.

Comment: Like Tom Harrington said, you don't have to worry about your stack, NSPersistentDocument does this for you. I have a NSColor attribute in a document-based app, I simply store it as a Transformable. No problems with saving into a new file. I suggest you compare your project with a fresh document-based Xcode template. Or ask a question with more information on your NSColor problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't seem that `NSPersistentContainer` is relevant to apps using `NSPersistentDocument`. It's not used because it's not needed.

The main purpose of `NSPersistentContainer` is to handle setting up the Core Data stack and creating managed object contexts. But `NSPersistentDocument` already does that. It also has properties that allow the same things `NSPersistentContainer` provides after setting up the stack. For example, if you need a new managed object context, get the coordinator using `managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator` and then just instantiate a new context object using that coordinator.

Comment: This is correct. But with the new `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` (a subclass of `NSPersistentContainer`), the question rises again. Can we hook a `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` on `NSPersistentDocument` to mirror documents into CloudKit?

Comment: An `NSPersistentDocument` should be able to be saved to iCloud Drive. `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` syncs the data to CloudKit records.